# Error in Spring : org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:

Tags: spring, spring-security, web.xml, pom.xml, applicationcontext

I am facing this error in integration of spring security :

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   bean named 'springSecurityFilterChain' is defined

This is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.server.rest</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringRestWebServices</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>SpringRestWebServices</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <!-- Shared version number properties -->
    <properties>
        <org.springframework.version>3.1.3.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <!-- Jersey dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-json</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->      <!-- Web application development utilities applicable to both Servlet and 
            Portlet Environments (depends on spring-core, spring-beans, spring-context) 
            Define this if you use Spring MVC, or wish to use Struts, JSF, or another 
            web framework with Spring (org.springframework.web.*) -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>       <!-- Spring 3 security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Jersey + Spring dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey.contribs</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-spring</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.5</source>
                    <target>1.5</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

and this is my applicationContext.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.server.rest.resource" />
</beans>
```

and this is ApplicationContext class :

```
@Configuration //This is a configuration class:  @Bean methods are intercepted, and it's return //values cached as needed for the bean scope.
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.server.rest.resource") //Transaction management 
@ImportResource("/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml") 
public class ApplicationContext {

}
```

and this is my spring-security.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd    
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security  http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <security:http auto-config="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/rest*" access="ROLE_USER" />
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:user-service>
                <security:user name="user" password="user" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </security:user-service>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

</beans>
```

and my web.xml

```
       <!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?? -->
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemalocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <display-name>SpringJerseyRestServer</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>    <!-- Configure ContextLoaderListener to use AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext 
        instead of the default XmlWebApplicationContext -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>           org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext       </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Configuration locations must consist of one or more comma- or space-delimited 
        fully-qualified @Configuration classes. Fully-qualified packages may also 
        be specified for component-scanning -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>           com.server.rest.resource.ApplicationContext,            /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml        </param-value>
    </context-param>


    <!-- Bootstrap the root application context as usual using ContextLoaderListener -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Declare a Spring MVC DispatcherServlet as usual -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>        <!-- Configure DispatcherServlet to use AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext 
            instead of the default XmlWebApplicationContext -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>
                    org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext           </param-value>
        </init-param>       <!-- Again, config locations must consist of one or more comma- or space-delimited 
            and fully-qualified @Configuration classes -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>com.server.rest.resource.ApplicationContext,
                    /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml

                </param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Spring Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.server.rest.resource</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Spring Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>


</web-app>
```

I would greatly appreciate it if you can help me solve tnis problem. Thanks in advance

Comment: I updated my answer with some explanations of what your web.xml file should look like. Try it, then go read up on Spring configuration/bean contexts.

Comment: Thank you very much @SotiriosDelimanolis ,I greatly appreciate your help. I fixed my problem by combining the two xml files : spring-security.xml and applicationContext.xml. Thank you very much I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring's `DelegatingFilterProxy` expects a bean having the name declared in `<filter-name>`. In your case, this is `springSecurityFilterChain`, but it doesn't seem like you have such a bean in your application context.

Take a look at the last post in [this](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?53972-Problem-when-finding-springSecurityFilterChain-bean) thread.

It seems like you need to explicitly use the `security` namespace for Spring to generate a `springSecurityFilterChain`. So add the namespace to all your `spring-security.xml` elements. (Make sure to change the default namespace to `beans` or something else.)

Replace with

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd    
                        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security  http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">

    <security:http auto-config="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/rest*" access="ROLE_USER" />
    </security:http>

    <security:authentication-manager>
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:user-service>
                <security:user name="user" password="user" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
            </security:user-service>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

</beans>
```

There are other things wrong/not needed in your web.xml. It should be like this:

```
<!--?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?? -->
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemalocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <display-name>SpringJerseyRestServer</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>    <!-- Configure ContextLoaderListener to use AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext 
        instead of the default XmlWebApplicationContext -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Configuration locations must consist of one or more comma- or space-delimited 
        fully-qualified @Configuration classes. Fully-qualified packages may also 
        be specified for component-scanning -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>           
            com.server.rest.resource.ApplicationContext
        </param-value>
    </context-param>


    <!-- Bootstrap the root application context as usual using ContextLoaderListener -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Declare a Spring MVC DispatcherServlet as usual -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>        <!-- Configure DispatcherServlet to use AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext 
            instead of the default XmlWebApplicationContext -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>
                    org.springframework.web.context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext
            </param-value>
        </init-param>       <!-- Again, config locations must consist of one or more comma- or space-delimited 
            and fully-qualified @Configuration classes -->
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>
                /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Spring Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.server.rest.resource</param-value>
        </init-param>

        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Spring Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- Spring Security -->
    <filter>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The root context of your application is loaded by the ContextLoaderListener. You should only put ApplicationContext context (your `@Configuration` class) to be loaded by it. All other contexts loaded by your `DispatcherServlet` are children of the root context and can therefore reference beans inside it. There your `DispatcherServlet` needs only to load the `/WEB-INF/spring-security.xml` context (and possibly a context with MVC related beans, but it doesn't look like you have that here.) Since this is an xml file, you need a `XmlWebApplicationContext`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but I don't really understand what I have to add

Comment: I still can't fix my problem please I need help.

Comment: Do you understand how xml namespaces work? In your `spring-security.xml` file, prefix all security elements with `security:`, for example `<authentication-manager>` becomes `<security:authentication-manager>`. But you also need to change your namespace declarations.

Comment: Yes I did change in my spring-security.xml file all security elements with security:

Comment: But what you mean by changing my namespace declarations?

Comment: Does your `spring-security.xml` look like mine. The namespace declarations are the `xmlns:security` attributes in the root element, defining namespaces for the elements used in the xml file.

Comment: Replace AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext with  XmlWebApplicationContext as your dispatcher contextClass and remove the com.server.rest.resource.ApplicationContext from the contextConfigLocation

Comment: @Wijden Can you update/edit your question with your updated web.xml and spring-security.xml configurations?